# How can I execute a shell script on linux directly from a URL if it needs to change environment variables?

Tags: linux, shell

Goals:

- One-liner script execution
- Changes environment variables in the caller

Is this possible?

I know you can do something like `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.29.0/install.sh | bash`, but this doesn't allow changing environment variables in the calling environment.

Comment: Why the downvote and close vote? Is this off topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*process substitution*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) together with the `.` (*source*) command:

```
. <(curl https://www.server.com/env.sh)
```

This would import all variable, alias and function definitions from `env.sh` into the scope of the running shell. However, it would not implicitly *export* the variables to the environment. To achieve this `export` has to be explicitly called in `env.sh` or the calling shell. Like this:

```
export FOO="test"
```

Comment: Do you know what shells this is supported in (or how to find that info)?

Comment: Process substitution is defined by POSIX. Meaning it is supported by all POSIX shells. You should use the dot `.` instead of `source` for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Dot? I'm a bit confused why you're recommending something that isn't in your answer up there. What do you mean by "You should use the dot"?

Comment: I'm used to the `source` command. However it is just an alias of the `.` I'm using `source` in my answers since it is more expressive. If you ask for compatibility; use the `.`

Comment: I would appreciate that being added to the answer! I'm definitely for compatibility. Tho if source is supported by all posix shells, how can `.` be more compatible than that? In any case, compatibility is more important to me than expressiveness in this case - if I wanted expressiveness I wouldn't be using a shell script ; )

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary environment variables will never be exported to child process.
You either have to explicitely `export` them, or tell the calling shell to provide a given environment variable by prepending it's definition to the call:

```
curl -o- ${URL2SCRIPT} | FOO="test1" bash
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like this sets an environment variable in the *calling* environment (not the child process environment created by a pipe to bash).

Comment: ah, i misunderstood the question then. the basic idea is that *nothing* can change the environment of the caller (all processes are children of `PID 0` - and you wouldn't want any malicious code be able to change the `PATH` if `PID 0`, would you?) - only the caller itself can change it's own environment (this is what you do with `source`ing)